# Opciones en blanco al llenar un select con datos de base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy con un ejercicio y me ha salido algo muy raro, cuando lleno un select con datos de la base de datos me salen entre una opción y otra, "otra opcion" pero en blanco. No se si la consulta o la forma de hacerlo está mal.

Os dejo el código

```
<?php
require_once 'php/conexion.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cod,nombre FROM familia');
$stmt ->execute();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tienda</title>
    <h1>Tarea: Listado de productos de una familia</h1>
    <p> Familia: <select>
    <option value="0" selected>Seleccione una opción..</option>
    <?php
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['cod'];?>"><?php echo $row['nombre'];?><option/>
    <?php
      }
   ?>
</select> </p>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Los `option` no parecen tener ningún problema, puede que sean los datos los que estén mal. Eso podrás saberlo muy fácilmente revisando la tabla en la BD haciendo algo así dentro del `while`: **`echo "cod: $row[cod] nombre: $row[nombre]\n";`** Si hay saltos sabrás que son los datos los que vienen así.

Comment: Hice lo que decías y nada, no viene ningún salto en blanco

Comment: No veo nada raro. No obstante prueba a poner el `while` así: **`<?php
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
  echo "<option value=\"$row[cod]\">$row[nombre]<option/>";
 }
   ?>`** Si muestra los saltos puede ser alguna regla CSS u otra cosa que afecta a los elementos `select` o a los elementos `option`. Si no funciona revisa el código fuente de la página y compártenos la parte del `select` para ver si encontramos algo...

Comment: Utiliza `print_r($row)` dentro del while para ver que datos tiene $row en blanco